# How to delete file in a dir using php script

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, codeigniter-2

I want to delete an image inside my profile_images folder.
I tried

```
unlink(base_url() . "_profile_images/912aea1dd8144e07894f788978b917d3.jpg");
```

and an error occured

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

```
Message: unlink() [function.unlink]: http does not allow unlinking

Filename: controllers/controller.php

Line Number: 100
```

I used codeigniter to implement this action. Is there another way to delete file?

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to delete a URL string, you should get php to get you the full path and filename to the file to be able to **unlink** it.

Not sure what your path is, but PHP has several functions which should help you get the full directory path to the file.

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; // Will get you PHP's document root, it's a good start.
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the actual filesystem reference on your server and not the URL ... so

unlink('/var/www/image_folder/file.jpg');

The parameter being the location of your file.